# how to give shift enter in latex as in microsoft office word

Tags: line-breaking

in few cases i need shift enter to move the word to next line 
in MS word by giving shift enter that word moves to next line
how to do in latex?

Comment: That's an editor question but not a LaTeX - related one! I think your text editor can do this.

Comment: i just like to know how to move the last word in a line to next line

Comment: are you looking for a forced linebreak like `one two\\ three` ? if not could you clarify the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are describing the action of

```
\linebreak
```

Here's an example

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Some words in a line so that we arrive somewhat near to the right margin
and go beyond it by adding more words.

Some words in a line so that we arrive somewhat near to the right \linebreak margin
and go beyond it by adding more words.

\end{document}
```

[image]